# Wifi not detected on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, wireless

I am new to Ubuntu 16.04. on my Dell laptop

I was using windows10 and i did a dual boot in my pc.

It looks everything is good but i am not able to detect wifi connection.

when i did `iwconfig`

```
enp7s0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

After using this `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`

```
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1704 802.11n + BT 4.0 [1028:0016]
    Kernel modules: bcma, wl
```

this above error was showing.

But my wifi is working fine in my window10.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 please check my updated question

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in BIOS.

Comment: it asked the password and after restarting the system i gave change boot state then i entered the password but it says it is not correct password

Comment: It is much easier to disable secure boot in bios than using mokutil. If you want to use mokutil, you need to carefuuly read the directions. In some cases it does not ask for a password, but to enter some characters of a password, like 1st, 3rd, etc. But I suggest to get into BIOS and simply disable it there.

Comment: got is thank you very much it realy helped me please answer it i will accept it

Comment: I updated the other answer with some more details. You can upvote it there. I will not write an answer here since the question is a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `bcmwl-kernel-source`.

For installing this go to your terminal and give `sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source` command. Do a reboot after completing the installation and give this `sudo modprobe wl` command on the terminal.

Hope that's gonna fix your problem.

Comment: after using this `sudo modprobe wl` i am getting this `modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Required key not available`

Comment: `bcmwl-kernel-source` is already installed. It is shown by `wl` kernel module.

Comment: Can you please try this `sudo ifconfig wlp4s0 up service network-manager restart`. Let me know what happens.

Comment: There is no need in that. The problem is with Secure Boot.

Comment: Do you mind telling what was the problem with Secure Boot?